# stringWithFormat vs initWithFormat under ARC

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, nsstring, automatic-ref-counting

`stringWithFormat:` is a class method of `NSString`, and returns an autoreleased string; `initWithFormat:` is an instance method, and before ARC the programmer had to take care of the returned object's memory management. If we have ARC turned on, what is the difference between the two methods?

Comment: They're the same. I prefer `stringWithFormat:` since it's shorter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `ARC` enabled, these two methods are equivalent (i.e. `ARC` will auto-call `autorelease` method; always registering to nearest `@autoreleasepool`).

See:

- [WWDC 2011 Session Video - Introducing Automatic Reference
  Counting](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=323)
- [WWDC 2011 Session Video - Objective-C Advancements
  In-Depth](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=322) (explains how ARC code compiles)

Answer (score 2):

If ARC is turned on there should be no difference.

You would typically call `initWithFormat:` after you've allocated your NSString, so the retain count ***without*** ARC would be 1 greater than if you used the autoreleased class method to create your string (thus you would have to remember to release it).

With ARC, there is no difference, because retain/release/autorelease is completely handled for you.