# Getting NSString from char * (Converting C's char-pointer)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to show the `char *` in the `UITextField`

What I tried:

```
char *data;
char *name=data+6;
txtName.text=[[NSString alloc] initWithCString:name encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

but I am not getting the correct value.

Comment: What are you getting in that field ?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

To create an `NSString` from a `const char *`, simply use these methods:

### Returns an `autorelease`d object:

```objectivec
/**
 * Should be wrapped in `@autoreleasepool {...}`,
 * somewhere not far in call-stack
 * (as closer it's, the lower our memory usage).
 */
NSString *stringFromChar(const char *input) {
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String: input];
}
```

> Whenever we `return` an object (maybe to `Swift`), we need to register into nearest `@autoreleasepool` block (by calling `autorelease` method to prevent memory-leak, according to [ownership-rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html)), but `ARC` does that automatically for us.

But even with `ARC` disabled, we are NOT forced to call `autorelease` manually, like:

```objectivec
return [[NSString stringWithUTF8String: name] autorelease];
```

> *Generally*, convenience factory methods (like `stringWithUTF8String:`), already call the `autorelease` method (or should if `ARC` disabled), because the class simply does not intend to own the instance.

### Creates a `retain`ed object:

```objectivec
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: name];

// ... Do something with resulted object.

// NOTE: calling below is not required
// (If ARC enabled, and should cause compile error).
[result release];
```

> Update 2021 [about difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7960952/8740349); With `ARC` enabled, these two methods are equivalent (i.e. `ARC` will auto-call `autorelease` method; always registering to nearest `@autoreleasepool`).

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithUTF8String:).

If you are not getting the correct value, then something is wrong with the data.  Add a few `NSLog` calls to see what the strings contain.

Comment: I couldn't follow all the edits on this one, but all I know is that in manual-reference-counting, `[[NSString stringWithUTF8String: name] autorelease];` will produce an over-released string. The `+stringWithUTF8String:` convenience method already produces an autoreleased string. There's no need to further release it unless you've retained it elsewhere.

Answer (score 10):

What do you expect? You have an uninitalized char*. Then you add 6 to the pointer, which is already undefined behaviour. Then you try to turn a pointer pointing to any old rubbish (and you have no idea where it is pointing) to an NSString*. Nothing good can come from this.

Define a char* pointing to an actual, real C string using ASCII or UTF-8 encoding. Then create an NSString like this:

```
char* cstring = "Try harder";
NSString* objcstring = @(cstring);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `[NSString stringWithUTF8String: data]`.