# How to get the a value of particular key out of Cocoa's NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, go, cgo

```
package getlark

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -x objective-c
#cgo LDFLAGS: -framework Cocoa
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <CoreGraphics/CGWindow.h>

static NSDictionary* FindChrome(void){
        NSArray *windows = (NSArray *)CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements|kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly,kCGNullWindowID);
        NSLog(@"数组长度:%lu",windows.count);
        for(NSDictionary *window in windows)
            {
                NSString *currentApp = window[(NSString *)kCGWindowOwnerName];
                NSString *currentWindowTitle = window[(NSString *)kCGWindowName];
                if ([currentApp isEqualToString:@"Google Chrome"]){
                    NSDictionary *currentBounds= window[(NSString *)kCGWindowBounds];
                    NSLog(@"%@",currentBounds);
                    return currentBounds;
                    break;
                }
            }
}
*/
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func GetLarkPos() {
    var dd *C.NSDictionary

    dd = C.FindChrome()
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(dd))
    fmt.Println(dd)

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0BDq.png)
The value on the picture, how can I call the function of golang

Sorry, I am not familiar with cgo and objective-c. I hope I can get some help from you.

Comment: In fact, my ultimate goal is to get the location of other software windows through golang. If you have an answer or golang has a better solution, you can let me know.

Comment: There's no question in your question. You show some code and, if I get it correctly, a screenshot of the output `GetLarkPos()` produces, when called. But then there's no actual problem statement. What do you want to ask?

Comment: @kostix 科斯蒂克斯 Objective-c, what is actually returned is a NSDictionary*, type of (* getlark._Ctype_struct_NSDictionary). I received it with dd in GetLarkPos (). How can I get the value of dd? I tried dd.Height,dd ["Height"], dd {}, but could not get the value of Height.

Comment: Thanks, I see now: you want to get a value _from_ the returned `NSDictionary` using some key.

Comment: @kostix Yes, I want to get the contents of the return value of dd in GetLarkPos (), but I don't know how to unlock it.

Comment: …in order to try to clear some magic around what you're observing by calling `fmt.Print*` on the returned value–quite possibly the Cocoa's type embeds some sort of a "token" or a "handle" which is used to look up a real runtime-allocated data structure when you're accessing entries that an `NSDictionary` holds. Go "sees" it as an array of 8 bytes (which is quite likely a 64-bit integer in fact, but I'd not guess further, as it's opaque anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `cgo`-generated `getlark._Ctype_struct_NSDictionary` is certainly not a Go `map` so `dd["Height"]` won't obviously work. Please note that `cgo` is a rather thin layer, it does not do any special magic like somehow turning random implementations of assotiative arrays done in C into Go `map`s.

What you should probably do is to write helper code in your C part (that bit which defined `GetChrome`) which would operate on `NSDictionary`s. Say, something like this (completely untested):

```
char *getNSDictInt(NSDictionary *dict, char *key) int {
  s_key = convertKeyToNSString(key); /* must be implemented */
  return dict[s_key];
}
```

and then call them like this:

```golang
dd := C.FindChrome()
height := C.getNSDictInt(dd, "Height")
```

You'd need to provide such "accessors" for each type of values your `NSDictionary` may hold.

(!) Note that after some digging I found out that the keys in a `NSDictionary` are `NSString`s which are sequences of UTF-16 code units, so you must use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10797380/720999) to get an `*NSString` out of the incoming `char *key`. (This can also be done on the Go side, but let's start small.)

Another solution should be to get a ready-made package which is already prepared to deal with Cocoa API's code types–such as [this](https://github.com/progrium/macdriver) or [this](https://github.com/danielpaulus/go-ios)–which both were found by a [simple search](https://www.google.com/search?q=golang+NSDictionary).

Comment: @sgx, please pay attention to that `char*`→`*NSString` conversion problem which I have overlooked initially (I have no exposure to Cocoa).

Comment: Okay, thank you for following up on this question. I'll try.

Comment: @sgx, oh, and one more note. The solution proposed in this answer presupposes you might want to deal with _any_ `NSDictionary` values. If, instead, your problem is quite narrow, and you'd want to basically only deal with "coordinates of windows", and nothing more, a better approach would be to define a custom `struct` type in your C code, with four `int`-typed fields, and merely "gateway" values of the fields of interest from the returned `NSDictionary` into the fields of a variable of that custom type, and returning that variable. At the call site–in Go code–you'd then work with plain fields.